# if statement string compare does not start intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, if-statement

in my app I would like the user to enter a 4 digit pin correctly to be able to continue to the next screen as a sort of "faux" authentication process. (This is just for a demo)
How does one set up a correct "if" statement to verify the user input is the correct numbers? I have the following java code:
-after the first button click and inputing "0000" it goes back to the original screen.
-after the second button click, it then takes me right to the second/next screen

```
    private void pincheck() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        // get prompts.xml view
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

        if (userInput.getText().toString().equals("0000")) {
            //moves to the "DoorControl xml page"
            Intent i = new Intent(this, LogIn.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // get user input and set it to result
                // edit text
                result.setText(userInput.getText());
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
              });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();

     }
}
```

Thank you I have been at this for hours and can't figure out the best way to do this! It either crashes or doesn't change the intent to "Door Control" page.

Thank you for any help/links/advice. :)

mainactivity XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wood"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llProfile"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProfilePic"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AUTOLOCK"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="70sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_revoke_access"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lock Control"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_out"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_logout_from_google"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Revoke Access"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

prompts XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type Your Message : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

loginscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/wood"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".login" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="AUTOLOCK"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:text="Door is:"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:text="Door is:"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Lock" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Unlock" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtArduino"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Sample Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogIn.java

```
package com.example.autolock;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LogIn extends Activity {
  private static final String TAG = "bluetooth2";

  Button btnOn, btnOff;
  TextView txtArduino;
  Handler h;

  final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 1;        // Status  for Handler
  private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
  private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
  private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

  // SPP UUID service
  private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

  // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
  private static String address = "00:13:12:06:48:79";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);

    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);                  // button LED ON
    btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);                // button LED OFF
    txtArduino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArduino);      // for display the received data from the Arduino

    h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // if end-of-line,
                    String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                    txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);            // update TextView
                    btnOff.setEnabled(true);
                    btnOn.setEnabled(true); 
                }
                //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                break;
            }
        };
    };

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
    checkBTState();

    btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
//        btnOn.setEnabled(true);
        mConnectedThread.write("1");    // Send "1" via Bluetooth
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Door is locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });

    btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
//        btnOff.setEnabled(true);  
        mConnectedThread.write("0");    // Send "0" via Bluetooth
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Door is unlocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
  }

  private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
          try {
              final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
              return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
          }
      }
      return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
    try {
      btSocket.connect();
      Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      try {
        btSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
      }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

    try     {
      btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
  }

  private void checkBTState() {
    // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if(btAdapter==null) { 
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
    } else {
      if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
      } else {
        //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  private void errorExit(String title, String message){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
  }

  private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                    h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(String message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Data to send: " + message + "...");
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");     
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat below:

```
   04-30 21:14:30.070: D/dalvikvm(10939): GC_CONCURRENT freed 569K, 10% free 17853K/19655K, 
paused 14ms+16ms, total 101ms
04-30 21:14:30.242: D/bluetooth2(10939): ...Bluetooth ON...
04-30 21:14:30.242: D/bluetooth2(10939): ...onResume - try connect...
04-30 21:14:30.250: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(10939): initSocketNative
04-30 21:14:30.250: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(10939): ...fd 40 created (RFCOMM, lm = 0)
04-30 21:14:30.250: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(10939): initSocketFromFdNative
04-30 21:14:30.414: D/bluetooth2(10939): ...Connecting...
04-30 21:14:30.429: D/BluetoothUtils(10939): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
04-30 21:14:35.593: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(10939): abortNative
04-30 21:14:35.593: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(10939): ...asocket_abort(40) complete
04-30 21:14:35.593: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(10939): destroyNative
04-30 21:14:35.593: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(10939): ...asocket_destroy(40) complete
04-30 21:14:35.593: D/bluetooth2(10939): ...Create Socket...
04-30 21:14:35.617: I/Choreographer(10939): Skipped 327 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: what does `System.out.println (userInput.getText().toString());` show?

Comment: When your app crashed what error was logged in the logcat?

Comment: Please post the error log.

Comment: Logcat is posted. New update- when I click the button the first time and input the code "0000" it goes back to the main screen. But after the second button push it THEN goes to the next screen.
Ideas???

Comment: ok, please upload the whole code of this activity.

Comment: Ok, I have uploaded the whole code of the activity. Please let me know if you happen to catch anything.

Comment: Answer updated below.

Answer (score 1):

Found my error: I was checking to see if the edittext on the activitymain.xml was set to "0000". Not the edittext directly in the prompts.xml.

I moved the if statement to within the onclick for the "OK" button.

If anyone would be so kind as to mark this question one up so my score isn't hurt I would so greatly appreciate it :)